# Automatic call to restart a local window service, Privileges issue

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a problem with setting the Admin privileges in a propper way; I have already tried ServiceController & ServiceControllerPermission, and it failed, cannot find any solution on the internet which will solve my problem. Code written below:

```
public class Restarter
    {
        public string Run(string serviceName)
        {
            var ctlPrms = new ServiceControllerPermission(ServiceControllerPermissionAccess.Control, Environment.MachineName, serviceName);
            ctlPrms.Assert();
            var srvCtl = new ServiceController(serviceName, Environment.MachineName);
            srvCtl.Refresh();
            var msg = $"At the beginning, Service: {srvCtl.DisplayName} has status of: {srvCtl.Status}!\n";
            if (srvCtl.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running))
            {
                msg = msg + "Attempting to stop running service\n";
                srvCtl.Stop();
                srvCtl.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
            }
            else
            {
                msg = msg + "Attempting to start the service\n";
                srvCtl.Start();
                srvCtl.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
            }
            msg = msg + $"At the end, Service: {srvCtl.DisplayName} has status of: {srvCtl.Status}!";

            return msg;
        }
    }
```

I will be more than gratefull for help with that, I'm already pulling my hair out because of it

Comment: Which line is failing?

Comment: _"and it failed"_ - **how**? Is an exception thrown? Does it run through just has no effect? How do you know it failed in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for answers, for the future usage; In order to make our code able to restart a windows service we need Administrative Privileges, in order to receive such, our program needs to have a manifest file, and those privileges are specified in it. Most important, this file needs to be named same as the project, in this case: "Restarter.manifest"

Comment: I already have solved the problem.